# Submit a Firefox OS application

Tags: firefox-os

After I developped my Firefox OS application, I submitted it on the marketplace. After a few days, my queue position became 10 of xx (and didn't move) :

**Created: May 29, 2013
Status: Pending approval
Packaged App Version: 0.6.1
Queue position: 10 of 108
Estimated waiting time: 1 working day
Price: FREE**

Since a few weeks, it became 5 of xx and didn't move neither :

**Created: May 29, 2013
Status: Pending approval
Packaged App Version: 0.6.1
Queue position: 5 of 108
Estimated waiting time: 1 working day
Price: FREE**

So, since a lot of weeks, the estimated waiting time is stopped to "1 working day".

When is my app supposed to be released and is it a known issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app validation is manual. So the time for validating an app can be long.

Mozilla looks for new reviewers for improving this time (Source : https://blog.mozilla.org/apps/2013/05/20/become-a-marketplace-app-reviewer/)

Comment: So, we can't trust the queue position and the estimated waiting time ?

Comment: The review process depends on volunteers and is not quick. I waited three weeks to get my app reviewed and then another week and a half when they found problems with the manifest file, problems that were not picked up by the manifest validator.

Comment: I think you can trust the queue position, but not the estimated waiting time, badly :(

Comment: I can't because a lot of apps appears in the marketplace while my app is still blocked to 10, or 5 or (now) 4.